# shell script not printing value

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am a newbie in shell programming trying to run the below script. I am unsuccessful in printing the value assigned to the **hadoop_home** variable in the below example. Please help me in understanding my mistake.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Holaaaa"
hadoop_home= echo "$HADOOP_HOME"
java_home= echo "$JAVA_HOME"
echo "Printing variable values"
echo "${hadoop_home}"
echo "${java_home}"
```

On executing the above shell, it prints

```
Holaaaa
/usr/hdp/2.6.0.1-152/hadoop/
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/
Printing variable values
```

The variable value in hadoop_home and java_home is empty. Why is it empty and how can I get the values assigned to these variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assignments must not have spaces around the `=`. To capture the output of a command use `$(cmd)`.

```
hadoop_home=$(echo "$HADOOP_HOME")
```

This can be simplified to:

```
hadoop_home=$HADOOP_HOME
```

Comment: Thank you. Removing space after '=' and adding $HADOOP_HOME solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `echo` and the double quotes from around the variables.

The `echo` command just prints to the standard output, it does not assign any values to the variables in your case as you are not in the standard output. You can capture the result though with a slight change:

```
$(echo "$HADOOP_HOME")
```

Comment: Thank you. I accepted John answer because removing spaces has solved my problem completely. Thank you for your response